# Is there a fix for the flutter audioplayers issue in my case?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-audioplayers

I am trying to run a project on my machine. Flutter version is 3.7.3 JDK is 11. The projects runs fine on my friends machine but when i run i get this error.
`
A problem occurred configuring project ':audioplayers_android'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\NH1950\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\audioplayers_android-3.0.2\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':audioplayers_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':audioplayers_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> `

I have tried flutter clean multiple times, deleting the build and pubspec.lock file manually, resetting the emulators, tried to build on a pyhiscal device as well. Nothing work. Help would be appreciated :)